# MongoDb Bind_ip error: bind() failed errno:10049

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, spring-data-mongodb

My MongoDb Config file Content Is as below:

```
port=22000
bind_ip=127.0.0.1,192.168.1.121
auth=true
dbpath=D:\Data_For_Mongo
```

I am running my mongod instance using following command:

```
mongod -f "D:\mongoConfig.conf"
```

It Gives Me following Error:

```
ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:10049 The requested address is not valid in its context. for socket: 192.168.1.121:22000
```

The Whole Stack trace is As Below:

```
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.600 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3780 port=22000 dbpath=D:\Data_For_Mongo 64-bit host=SLK055
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.600 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.6
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.600 [initandlisten] git version: b9925db5eac369d77a3a5f5d98a145eaaacd9673
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.600 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.615 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.615 [initandlisten] options: { auth: "true", bind_ip: "192.168.1.80,192.168.1.121", config: "D:\mongoConfig.conf", dbpath: "D:\Data_For_Mongo", port: 22000 }
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.647 [initandlisten] journal dir=D:\Data_For_Mongo\journal
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.647 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.709 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:10049 The requested address is not valid in its context. for socket: 192.168.1.121:22000
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.709 [websvr] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:10049 The requested address is not valid in its context. for socket: 192.168.1.121:23000
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.709 [initandlisten] now exiting
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.725 dbexit:
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.725 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.740 [initandlisten] closing listening socket: 528
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.740 [initandlisten] closing listening socket: 552
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.740 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.756 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.756 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.772 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.772 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.834 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.834 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.834 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.834 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.850 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Fri Apr 11 09:24:18.850 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Bind Multiple ips is important for me.
Can AnyOne Help Me To Solve This Error?
I Have searched about error but can't find any way to bind multiple ips in mongo.

Comment: Off topic for this site really. But could be a bug in the version that I do not see in recent releases. Since this must be for your own machine, try installing a more recent release. Current is now 2.6.0 but at least try to move to 2.4.9

Comment: I have tried same with 2.6.0, still getting same error.

Comment: Sorry but I do not see that in anything above 2.4.8. Possibly you have unusual characters in your config file.

Comment: Is there any problem because of firewall?
I have run following command to accept connection from external ips:
`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Allowing mongod" dir=in action=allow program="D:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.6.0\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.6.0\bin"`

Comment: Possibly so, but I already flagged you as off topic because this is not a programming question

Comment: Have you tried bind_ip with multiple ips?
If so then can you provide content of your config file?

Comment: Just a line but yes `bind_ip=192.168.2.20,192.168.56.1`

Comment: I am not sure but your problem might be related to the port number you choose.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a [Windows Socket error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is normally due to the IP address you are trying to bind to not being the IP of your local machine. You should double check that your system actually has the IP of 192.168.1.121

Comment: Need to provide info on how to double check.